# JavaFX Slider reflect the same value as Progress Bar

Tags: slider, progress-bar, javafx-8

Situation:

1. Need slider (that is bind to Progress Bar ) to reflect from 0 to 100% on label.
2. Currently can only get 0 to 1 reflected in the label. See example.
3. I'm using JFoenix Library for slider.

[image]

Here is the code:
    public class Controller  implements Initializable{

```
 @FXML
private ProgressBar mProgress1, mProgress2;

@FXML
private ProgressIndicator mProgressIndicator;

@FXML
private JFXSlider mSlider1 , mSlider2;

@FXML
private TextField mTextField;
@FXML
private Label mLabel;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {



   mTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(mSlider1.valueProperty(),
           NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
           mLabel.textProperty().bind(mTextField.textProperty().concat("%"));



  mProgress1.progressProperty().bind(mSlider1.valueProperty());
  mProgress2.progressProperty().bind(mSlider2.valueProperty());



  mProgressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(mProgress1.progressProperty());
   }
}
```

xml:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="564.0" prefWidth="372.0" 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112"  
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
    fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="lowerPane" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="353.0" 
             prefHeight="211.0" prefWidth="361.0">
         <children>
            <ProgressBar fx:id="mProgress1" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="155.0"
                             prefWidth="205.0" progress="0.0" />
            <ProgressBar fx:id="mProgress2" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="137.0" 
        prefWidth="193.0" progress="0.0" />
           <Label fx:id="mLabel" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="189.0" text=" 
            Progress" />
          </children></AnchorPane>
      <TextField fx:id="mTextField" layoutX="286.0" layoutY="270.0" 
    prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="78.0" />
      <ProgressIndicator fx:id="mProgressIndicator" layoutX="313.0"  
           layoutY="301.0" 
    progress="0.0" />
      <JFXSlider fx:id="mSlider1" blockIncrement="0.0" 
              indicatorPosition="RIGHT" 
    layoutX="116.0" layoutY="275.0" max="1.0" />
      <JFXSlider fx:id="mSlider2" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="233.0" max="1.0" 
    value="0.1" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Two better direct my search, I there an explanation for the down vote?

Comment: Please post some code. How do you expect anyone to know why your code is not behaving the way you want it to, if we can't see it?

Comment: It will be better to post your code so we can do some modification.

Comment: So this is a question about the text displayed as part of the JFoenix slider? Unfortunately, that library doesn't publish any Javadocs, and without those or any reasonable documentation it's hard to know if there is even any way to configure that.

Comment: The label (on JFoenix slider )will go to 100% if it in not bind with the progress bar. When it is bind to the progress bar it only go from 0 to 1. Is there a workaround for this or is there another approach to take and get similar results, i.e. a label  that would display the percentage on the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProgressBar` and `ProgressIndicator` have Minimum of -1 and Maximum if 1.

So if your `JFoenixProgressBar` has  minimum 0 and maximum 1 it works ok.

Generally the value of your `ProgressIndicator` should be:

```
double indicatorValue=foenixProgressBarMaximumValue/foenixProgressBarCurrentValue;
```

Also add an if the `foenixProgressBarCurrentValue` is 0.Let's make it a ternary expression:

```
double indicatorValue=((foenixProgressBarCurrentValue!=0)?foenixProgressBarMaximumValue/foenixProgressBarCurrentValue:0);
```

To make it work as a binding you can make it a `DoubleProperty` or use `Bindings` class methods.

**Mention** that the above needs modification if both minimum and maximum are 0.